# Assign variable in inner SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, variables, select, nested, case

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(200)
SELECT et.ExampleField, (SELECT CASE (@Test = (SELECT 'Test')) WHEN @Test IS NOT NULL THEN @Test
ELSE
''
END) FROM ExampleTable et
```

For readability purposes I've simplified it a bit, but basically the `(SELECT 'Test')` bit could be any SQL `SELECT` statement pulling back one value (or `NULL`) for me to test against.

Can this be done?  The reason for me trying to do it this way is that I was hoping to make it efficient by removing the need for the nested select, in this example `(SELECT 'Test')`, from having to be run more than once, ie something like this, which does work:

```
DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(200)
SELECT et.ExampleField, (SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT 'Test') IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT 'Test')
ELSE
''
END) FROM ExampleTable et
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally those things are optimized from sql-server, so the sub-query is not executed multiple times.
However, you can use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT et.ExampleField, 
       COALESCE((SELECT ...),'') As Col
FROM ExampleTable et
```

Even simpler example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/15850

Comment: So it looks like I probably don't need to worry about the query being executed multiple times.  However, when you say these things are 'normally' optimized, are you saying there are circumstances where this can happen?  If so, are you able to give any examples?  Or would it be something so hideously complex that I'm unlikely to run into this scenario?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that T-SQL is Declarative language. So it takes care of the optimization. It won't do the select statement multiple number of times.